# R clustering produces error message

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, na

When trying to cluster I get the message:

> Error in diana(mat.in, stand = TRUE) : 
>    No clustering performed, NA's in dissimilarity matrix.

This is unexpected, as diana takes a matrix instead of a dissimilarity matrix. According to the documentation, NA's *are* allowed in the matrix [but not in the dissimilarity matrix].

Example:

```
require("cluster")
mat.in=data.frame(A=c(12,10,NA,14,12,60),B=c(NA,11,45,25,13,65))
d=diana(mat.in,stand=TRUE)
```

I have made sure that there are neither all-NA columns nor all-NA rows.

Anyone knows what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, at least with the example data, is that for samples 1 and 3 there is *no information* with which to compute the dissimilarity. Consider:

```
> daisy(mat.in)
Dissimilarities :
          1         2         3         4         5
2  2.828427                                        
3        NA 48.083261                              
4  2.828427 14.560220 28.284271                    
5  0.000000  2.828427 45.254834 12.165525          
6 67.882251 73.593478 28.284271 60.959003 70.767224

Metric :  euclidean 
Number of objects : 6
> mat.in
   A  B
1 12 NA
2 10 11
3 NA 45
4 14 25
5 12 13
6 60 65
```

Which explains that the `NA` in the dissimilarity matrix is real. For the comparison between sample 1 and 2, `A` is missing for sample 3 but present for 1, whilst the converse is true for `B`. As there is no data with which to compute the dissimilarity for these two samples you get an `NA` in the dissimilarity matrix.

Notice that `NA`s are clearly allowed as long as there remains some information to compute the dissimilarity; the matrix produced contains a dissimilarity between all samples and samples 1 and 3.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. My dataset is obviously more complex than this example, but you have put me in the right direction now.

Comment: @Henk I encountered the same problem using daisy() as well. My daisy function has NA values b/c of the partial fill rate in the data.frame. What did you do to solve it?