# Error in PAM function using R: NA values in the dissimilarity matrix not allowed

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I created a dissimilarity matrix using `daisy` then tried clustering using the `PAM` function, but got an error. The clustering method is used for a marketing segmentation study on consumer demographics.

According to another post, the error occurs when there are `NA` values for two samples. There's no way to compute the dissimilarity. Here's the link: [R Clustering Produces Error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638625/r-clustering-produces-error-message). It seems that my `data.frame` is so sparse, that the dissimilarity matrix has `NA` values.

**Question:** What's the best way for making the `daisy` matrix not have `NA` values? Should I fill in the ordinal columns?

I have 13163 observations of 34 `ordinal` and `NA` variables in a `data.frame` called Store4df. None of the rows in the `data.frame`have all `NA` values. Here's the code to check:

```
> which(rowSums(is.na(Store4df))==ncol(Store4df))
#named integer(0)
```

Here's a sample of the first 5 variables of 5 observations:

```
> head(Store4df, n=5)
    Age Gender HouseholdIncome MaritalStatus PresenceofChildren HomeOwnerStatus
2 55-64 Female         50k-75k        Single                 No             Own
3  <NA> Female            <NA>          <NA>               <NA>            <NA>
4  <NA>   Male            <NA>          <NA>               <NA>            <NA>
7  <NA>   Male            <NA>          <NA>               <NA>            <NA>
9   65+   Male        75k-100k        Single                 No             Own
```

I used the `PAM` clustering method from CRAN's `cluster`package with three clusters.

```
> #Import cluster package
> library(cluster)
> #Create dissimilarity matrix
> #Gower coefficient for finding distance between mixed variable
> daisy4 <- daisy(Store4df, metric = "gower", type = list(ordratio = c(1:34))) 
> #Pam algorithm with 3 clusters 
> k4answers <- pam(daisy4, 3, diss = TRUE)
> k4answers <- pam(daisy4, 3, diss = TRUE)
#Error in pam(daisy4, 3, diss = TRUE) : 
  #NA values in the dissimilarity matrix not allowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. For the ordinal values, I decided to take the median value and input into the `NA`'s. I cannot create a euclidean distance matrix with missing values. A distance cannot be computed between a value and something that is not there.